# enabling php-cli in php5

Tags: php, php-cli

i wanted to install php-cli in php5.2.11..does it come built-in or should i install it?

Comment: Depending on your platform, php-cli may be a separate package.

Comment: An emphatic and unqualified "maybe".

Answer (score 2):

On debian/ubuntu it's the `php5-cli` package, but without knowing what OS you're actually using there's no real answer.

Comment: Most (if not all) RHEL-based distro's is "php-cli".

"yum install php-cli" should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, on FreeBSD you have to reinstall php port and tick php-cli option during `make`